# Java output in lines of ten

Tags: java, arrays, output

I'm in a beginners java class and I have a quick question about the output statement on my array problem for week 5. So basically I have the core of the program down, but I'm supposed to output the result in lines of ten. I for some reason can not get it to work even with looking at similar posts on here. I'm a beginner and am pretty slow at putting 2 and 2 together when it comes to programming. Once I see it I have that ah-ha! moment and that's how this whole class has gone. I know I have to use the modulus, but in my trial and error I lost my way and have probably done more damage than good. Help would be appreciated.

Here is what I have and as you can tell I was trying something without modulus:

```
 import java.util.*;

   public class ArrayLoop 
   {
      public static void main(String args[])
      {
         double alpha[] = new double[50];
         *//Initialize the first 25 elements of the array (int i=0; i<25; i++)//*
            for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
         {
            alpha[i]= i * i;
         }
            *//Initialize the last 25 elements of the array (i=25; i<50; i++)//*
               for(int i = 25; i < 50; i++)
               {
               alpha[i]= 3 * i;
               }
               *//Print the element of the array*
                  System.out.println ( "The values are: " );
                  for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                  System.out.println ( alpha[i] );
               }
                  *//Print method to display the element of the array*
                  void print(double m_array[])
         {

                      for(int i = 1; i < m_array.length; i++)
                      {
                      if(i % 10 == 0){;
                      System.out.println();
                      }else{
                      System.out.print(" ");
                      }
                     }
                     if (m_array.length % 10 != 0) {
                     System.out.println();
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um .. this isn't eloquent in the least but I tried to make the fewest changes to your existing code sample.

```
public class ArrayLoop {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double alpha[] = new double[50];

        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            alpha[i] = i * i;
        }

        for (int i = 25; i < 50; i++) {
            alpha[i] = 3 * i;
        }

        System.out.println("The values are: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            System.out.print(alpha[i] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 1; i < alpha.length; i++) {
            if (i != 1 && i % 10 == 0) {
                System.out.print(alpha[i - 1] + " ");
                System.out.println();
            } else {
                System.out.print(alpha[i - 1] + " ");
            }

        }
        System.out.print(alpha[49]);
    }
}
```

Edit: A better condition would be ...

```
for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0 && i % 10 == 9) {
        System.out.print(alpha[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        System.out.print(alpha[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I see where this came from, but I don't see the error. When I ran this I got one long line of code after "the values are:" and then I got the block of numbers

Comment: Ok, remind me what you want to see. Just 5 lines of 10 numbers?

Comment: I got it thank you. I had an extra print under the "the values are:" that was outputing the entire numbers in a single line. take that out and combine your condition with my original code gave the correct output and more than that I UNDERSTAND WHY it works. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of `% 10` snippets in your code so I'm not *entirely* certain how that's "trying something without modulus" :-)

Having said that, modulus is *exactly* what you need, as per the following psuedo-code:

```
count = 0
for each item in list:
    if count > 0 and (count % 10) == 0:
        print end of line
    print item
print end of line
```

In Java, you would use something like:

```
public class Test {
    static public void main(String args[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            if ((i > 0) &&((i % 10) == 0)) {
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.print ("" + i * 3 + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

In other words, immediately before you print an item, check to see if it should be on the next line and, if so, output a newline before printing it.

Note that arrays in Java are *zero* based, so you need to start with an index of zero rather than one in your loops.

Now that's pretty *close* to what you have so you're on the right track but, for the life of me, I cannot see in your `print()` method where you actually *print the item!* That should be number one on your list of things to look into :-)

---

I *urge* you to try and work it out from the above text and samples but, if you're still having troubles after more than half an hour or so, the below code shows how I'd do it.

```
public class Test {
    static void print (double m_array[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_array.length; i++) {
            if ((i > 0) && ((i % 10) == 0))
                System.out.println();
            System.out.print (m_array[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    static public void main(String args[]) {
        double[] x = new double[15];
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
            x[i] = i * 3;
        print (x);
    }
}
```

Comment: psuedo code kills me because I have a hard time converting variables in my head. :D I see what you are saying I think, but I don't know how to translate it into my code. So in this which I assume is the first half of the program you are printing the elements as you go rather than at the end like I am?

Comment: I definitely wanna work it out on my own, but I have a terrible instructor and it's basically all up to me. I haven't found examples close enough with a good explanation to really be able to work it out. I ask the instructor questions and either get half ass answers or completely ignored. Needless to say this is stressing me out as I have zero experience. Thank you for your help and I will really try I promise and if I have trouble use this to work it out, not just copy.

Comment: I finally got it with a combination of everyone's input. I can't thank you enough for using your time to help me understand this. My code didn't end up looking like what you gave me, rather my original code. Your answers gave me insight into other methods for writing this, but I had trouble doing the whole problem in one array called "alpha" using this method because I ended up having two array's of 25 which were x and y and successfully printed them both. I couldn't find out how to combine them and print with one array called alpha. Your help was incredible and I appreciate your effort.

Comment: @Sammy, the normally accepted practice is to accept the answer which hepled you the _most_ (which you've done) and upvote all those others which helped you as well (which you haven't). Don't get me wrong, I appreciate the textual thanks but SO works better if useful answers have votes, so they can be sorted correctly for future use.

Answer (score 0):

You have to print the number first then decide whether to print space or newline by checking the modulus:

```
int arr[] = new int[50];
// Initialize array here

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(arr[i]);
    if (i > 0 && (i + 1) % 10 == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: You have that slightly bass-ackward :-) The first line will contain _11_ items (indexes 0 thru 10). This can be fixed by either swapping the print-item/output-newline segments, or by comparing to 9 rather than 0, the latter which removes the extra check for `i>0`.

Comment: when I tried to input this into my code i still got one per line although I feel im getting close
                  
                  void print(double m_array[])
         {
                      int arr[]  = new int[50];
                      for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
                      {
                      if(i % 10 == 0){;
                      System.out.println();
                      }else{
                      System.out.print(" ");
                      }
                     }
                     if (arr.length % 10 != 0) {
                     System.out.println()

Comment: @paxdiablo. I made an edit to the code. Just replace `i % 10 == 0` with `(i + 1 ) % 10 == 0`

Comment: @SammyJackson You should not start at index 1. Refer to my edited answer instead

Comment: I finally got the answer and I really appreciate the help and input you gave. I can't explain how much I value the time you put in and your effort to help me understand where I am coming up short.